# Debugging a Wildfly Application on Docker through Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, docker, wildfly

I've deployed a Wildfly application server using Docker as described here http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-02-getting-started-with-docker-and-wildfly.html, and I'm using it for development work in Eclipse.  Everything is working fine.  I'm able to deploy to a local directory and have it mapped to the Wildfly deployment directory with no problem.  The only thing I don't have working is debugging.  I'm unable to set breakpoints within Eclipse and debug the deployed application.  How do I go about doing this?  I wasn't able to find any documentation explaining how I could accomplish this in Eclipse and Docker.

Comment: When running in docker you will have your app running in a separate JVM in the docker VM. In order to debug it you will need to do remote debugging from eclipse against that JVM.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to do remote debugging against the running container, but before that, you will need to run container in debug mode and map debug port 8787

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 8787:8787 jboss/wildfly \ 
   /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --debug
```